# Linq count of records in a list

Tags: c#, linq, count

Trying to use expresisons and predicates to group a list by two types and take the count.
I have two lists: yearList and supList. They both contain columns called FIPS and YEAR and what I need to do is in one list I loop through all the possible FIPS and Years (yearList). I then need to find the count of how many times that FIPS and Year appears in the second list(supList) and write that int value to yearlLst.
Below you will find a sample of what the data looks like so for example when FIPS=1001 and Year=2001 form yearList is passed in I should return a count of 1 from my supList and write that value to y.countEnviofnd in my yearList and when FIPS=1001 and Year=2002 is passed in count=2 should be returned. Ive tried multiple wyas to try and do this but can't seem to get it.

This would be the sample list that I need to compare against and find the counts from: this would be supList in my code sample below.

```
FIPS    YEAR
------------
1001    2001
1001    2002
1003    2006
1002    2001
1001    2002
1003    2005
1003    2006
```

This would be all the possible FIPS and Years I could possibly have: starts at 1001 for fips and increases but also each fips has a record for year starting at 2001 and going up the 2004. There are lots more but here is a sample. In my code below this would be the yearList

```
FIPS    DATE
------------
1001    2001
1001    2002
1001    2003
1001    2004
1002    2001
1002    2002
1002    2003
1002    2004
1003    2001
1003    2002
1003    2003
1003    2004
```

Ive tried all these LINQ expressions and nothing seems to do it. It either returns 0 or 1 for everything.

```
foreach(Year y in yearList)
{
    int countY = supList.Where(p => p.FIPS == Convert.ToString(y.FIPS) && p.year==y.year).Count();
    int countY = supList.GroupBy(p => p.FIPS == Convert.ToString(y.FIPS) && p.year==y.year).Count();
    int countY  = supList.FindAll(i => i.FIPS == Convert.ToString(y.FIPS) && i.year == y.year).Count(); 

    y.countenviofnd = countY;
}
```

Comment: Could you post sample input (for both lists) and desired output?

Comment: It should work as long as there are no spaces or other strange characters in the `FIPS` strings.

Comment: Thats what I thoguht but it either returns 0 or 1 for eveyrthing which i know is not correct.

Comment: How do you read the data? You're probably missing a `.Trim` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Where()` and `Count()` will work, here's a sample I made in LINQPad 4:

```
void Main()
{
    var supList = new List<Data>() {
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2001 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2002 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2006 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1002, Year = 2001 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2002 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2005 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2006 }
    };

    var yearList = new List<Data>() {
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2001 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2002 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2003 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1001, Year = 2004 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1002, Year = 2001 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1002, Year = 2002 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1002, Year = 2003 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1002, Year = 2004 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2001 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2002 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2003 },
        new Data { FIPS = 1003, Year = 2004 },
    };

    foreach (var year in yearList)
    {
        supList
            .Where(p => p.FIPS == year.FIPS && p.Year == year.Year)
            .Count()
            .Dump(string.Format("Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:{0}, Year:{1}]", year.FIPS, year.Year));
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Data
{
    public int FIPS { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

I got the following output:

```
Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1001, Year:2001] 
1 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1001, Year:2002] 
2 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1001, Year:2003] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1001, Year:2004] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1002, Year:2001] 
1 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1002, Year:2002] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1002, Year:2003] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1002, Year:2004] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1003, Year:2001] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1003, Year:2002] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1003, Year:2003] 
0 

Using Where().Count() for [FIPS:1003, Year:2004] 
0
```

Note that I made my data of type `int`, avoiding any possible issues there. I would suggest you do the conversion once during/just-after data retrieval.

Also note that with the data you provided, only one FIPS/Year combo has more than 1 record (the second output).

Depending on your needs, you could probably do better with some kind of GroupBy expression.

UPDATE: for performance, assuming data types are already converted to compatible types you can add the following query to do counts per valid combo all at once:

```
var query = from year in yearList
            join sup in supList 
                on new { year.FIPS, year.Year } equals new { sup.FIPS, sup.Year }
            group sup by new { sup.FIPS, sup.Year } into p
            select new { p.Key.FIPS, p.Key.Year, Count = p.Count() };
query.Dump("join/group query");
```

The `Dump()` statement is just for LINQPad output, you could use `ToList()` or something. The result is 3 rows as follows:

```
FIPS Year Count
==== ==== =====
1001 2001 1
1001 2002 2
1002 2001 1
```

Note that it is a little more complex since I'm grouping by more than one key (thus the anon object with FIPS+Year).

Comment: Note that `.Where(...).Count()` can be simplified to `.Count(...)`.

Comment: what would be the best statement to use to improve speed?

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes, I simply used the OPs existing syntax to show that it worked. If I truly wanted to optimize for performance I wouldn't be doing LINQ Count() statements inside a loop, I would simply join the two lists and group/count.

Comment: @BS123 see update for a faster way to get all the results in a single query. You can extend it to show as much information as needed, but I do strongly suggest any string/int manipulation be done before building the query.